# Unable to display the material button properly and add underline only on tab name using Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am unable to display angular material button properly and also I need to display the angular tab in different way. I am explaining my code below.

> routes.component.html::

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="mdl-grid">
        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col panel--raised card-top bg-white">
            <div class="mdl-grid bottom-r-padding-0">
                <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col mdl-layout-spacer">
                    <div class="mdl-grid">
                        <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--12-col">
                            <mat-tab-group>
                                <mat-tab label="Manage"> Manage</mat-tab>
                                <mat-tab label="Create">
                                    <form class="example-form">
                                        <table class="example-full-width" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
                                                    <mat-label>Dist</mat-label>
                                                    <input matInput placeholder="e.x-Londrina">
                                                </mat-form-field> 
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <mat-form-field appearance="standard">
                                                    <mat-label>Route</mat-label>
                                                    <input matInput placeholder="e.g.: CTA-LDA">
                                                </mat-form-field>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <button mat-button color="success">Success</button>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </form>
                                </mat-tab>
                            </mat-tab-group>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

> routes.component.css::

```
.example-form {
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .example-full-width {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  td {
    padding-right: 8px;
  }
  
  
  /* Success syling */
  
  .mat-button.mat-success,
  .mat-stroked-button.mat-success {
      color: #155724;
  }
```

The above code gives the following output.

[image]

Here the success button is not coming properly with angular material button. Actually I need the output like below.

[image]

Here the above picture is my required output. The page should come like above. Also I need only underline should come under the tab name. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

For button,

```
 <button mat-raised-button color="primary">Primary</button>
```

For place holder,

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" floatLabel="always">
      <mat-label>Both a label and a placeholder</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="Simple placeholder">
    </mat-form-field>
```

Use the below css to change the Mat Tab color,

```
::ng-deep .mat-tab-list .mat-tab-labels .mat-tab-label-active {
color:rgb(0, 0, 0);
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

::ng-deep .mat-tab-list .mat-tab-labels {
color:blue;
background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

Comment: Button is working now. I dont for place holder. I need the underline should come under only selected tab.

Comment: for  the place holder use this,   <mat-form-field appearance="fill" floatLabel="always">

Comment: I have edited in the above code also , you can verify it.